# What is the fastest way of litecoin mining?

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, scrypt

I have searched whole the Internet but it looks like that there isn't any fast way of mining litecoin.

Most powerful CPUs just mine about 200 Kh/s and the most powerful GPUs mine around 900 Kh/s.

And I haven't seen any hardware like ASICs for litecoin mining yet.

So what is the fastest way of mining litecoin??? I think it's impossible to mine with a 4000$ gpu and just get 900 Kh/s so is any minig hardware going to be produced ???

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, all public manufacturers of scrypt asics has ceased their operations. This doesn't mean that there's no scrypt asics being produced, just that they aren't for sale on the open market. If you really want to mine, your best bet is to buy some used equipment on Ebay. However I doubt you'll be profitable, since you have to compete against huge Chinese farms with close to zero electricity costs.